# Fortsetzung vs fortgesetzt. Continuing a figure on next page

Tags: vocabulary

My figure streches over two pages. On the second page, what would you append to the figure title: *(Fortsetzung)*, *(Fortgesetzt)*, or something else? In English, I would probably write *(Continued)*

E.g.,

```
| Das Römische Reich                |
|                                   |
//                                  //
|                                   |
|                              S. 1 |

| Das Römische Reich (Fortsetzung)  |
|                                   |
//                                  //
|                                   |
|                              S. 2 |
```

Comment: Not sure that I understand the Question… You have a figure (a map? a timeline?) that spans two pages. Presumably these are facing pages. Why would you need to put a caption below the figure on the second page? I would just put a caption on the first page without (continued) or (Fortsetzung). If the pages are non-sequential, you would put "Weiter auf Seite XYZ" at the bottom of page 1 and "Fortsetzung von Seite 1" at the top of page XYZ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both is possible. However, *Fortsetzung* is more common. I learned to use *Fortsetzung*, so I recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

If you write it in Brackets, than use "(Fortsetzung)".

"fortgesetzt" is only used within a sentence. For example:

**Wrong: (especially in titles)** 
*"Die Reise (fortgesetzt)"*

**Right:**
*"Die Reise (Fortsetzung)"*     //as a Title of something
*"Die Reise wurde fortgesetzt."*         //as a sentence in a text